# 'WpfApplication1.Grid' does not contain a definition for 'SetColumn'

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a grid in my WPF main page, and I want the user to select the dimension of said grid (initially assuming a square grid, number of rows = number of columns). Once the dimensions are specified, I want the code to run through all the grid and place a colored label over each of the cells.

I've located the first label (in position 0,0), but I want to tell it that, for each iteration, the created label should be placed in Row(i), Column(j).

Thing is, when I try to use Grid.SetRow(etiqueta, i) an error pops up: 'WpfApplication1.Grid' does not contain a definition for 'SetRow', but I've read that the method is static, so I've got no clue what the problem could be.  Code:

```
{
    MyGrid.Children.Clear();
    MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
    MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < f; i++)
    {
        //Definimos las columas y las filas a la grid de la simulación.
        RowDefinition filas = new RowDefinition();
        MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(filas);
        ColumnDefinition columnas = new ColumnDefinition();
        MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnas);
        for(int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            Label etiqueta = new Label();
            etiqueta.Width = MyGrid.Width / c;
            etiqueta.Height = MyGrid.Height / f;

            MyGrid.ShowGridLines = true;

            //Definimos clase para pintar
            SolidColorBrush colorLabel = new SolidColorBrush();

            double fase = m.GetCelda(i, j).GetFase();
            //etiqueta.ToolTip = fase.ToString("0.####");
            byte[] RGBFase = Color_Fase(fase);
            colorLabel.Color = Color.FromRgb(RGBFase[0], RGBFase[1], RGBFase[2]);
            etiqueta.Background = colorLabel;

            //Introducimos las celdas para luego poder seleccionarlas.
            Grid.SetRow(etiqueta, i);
            Grid.SetColumn(etiqueta, j);

            //Introducimos estas celdas en la graella para poder controlar su fondo.
            MyGrid.Children.Add(etiqueta);
        }
    }
}
catch (NullReferenceException) // Por si cerramos sin introducir datos, para que no pete
{

}
```

Comment: Note that the error message does not refer to the WPF control `Grid`, whose full name would be `System.Windows.Controls.Grid` and not `WpfApplication.Grid`. I assume _WpfApplication_ is the default namespace in your project. I further assume, that you have your own type (class?) named Grid defined somewhere in your project, which the compiler would pick when confronted with a code line like _Grid.SetRow(...)_ in your project. And since your own Grid type would not be the WPF Grid type, the compiler would fail finding the SetRow method there... (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Preferred Solution (assuming my assumption is correct): Refactor your Grid class in your project to some name other than "Grid", so the compiler will not pick the wrong class when resolving member/method names. Alternate (less preferrable) solution: Write `System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetRow(...)` instead of just _Grid.SetRow(...)_.

Comment: It was just as you said, shame on me for not noticing before. Cheers!